# Doxygen for php doesn't handle default parameter array

Tags: php, arrays, parameters, default, doxygen

I tried searching a solution for my problem, but I can't find anything. My problem is that doxygen for php doesn't handle default parameters if they are an array:

**Code:**

```
/**
 * @brief convert rgb values to hexa decimal, and return array.
 * @param  int $red   : 0 - 255
 * @param  int $green : 0 - 255
 * @param  int $blue  : 0 - 255
 * @param  array  $default
 * @return array
 */
public static function rgb2hex(
    int   $red   = 0,
    int   $green = 0,
    int   $blue  = 0,
    array $default = ['r' => 0, 'g' => 0, 'b' => 0]
) : array {
...
    return [
        'r' => $r,
        'g' => $g,
        'b' => $b
    ];
}
```

**Rendering:**

[image: Doxygen PHP parameter array default values rendering]

Screen sample: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJhiu.png

Comment: Hi Jens, if you think this is a bug, have you considered to check the projects homepage if its already known?

Comment: Which version of doxygen did you use. Which settings did you use that are different from the default doxygen settings (in the newer versions the result of `doxygen -x`)?

Comment: It looks like doxygen doesn't like the `=>` construct. Best is, when no issue present for this problem at https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues, to file a new issue for this.

Comment: Hi albert,
>doxygen -x
error: Doxyfile not found and no input file specified!
Doxygen version 1.9.1 (ef9b20ac7f8a8621fcfc299f8bd0b80422390f4b)
Copyright Dimitri van Heesch 1997-2021

The config i here:
https://dpaste.com/FVTHUG56G

Sorry for the length, but the wizard seems to be add more comment as requiered.

and here is a snippet for a filter:
https://dpaste.com/G5238KGVK

But I don't realy know, how to use this as input_filter - i would change the php source commenting, but i am very new in doxygen

Comment: @Jens I missed this comment at first. In the doxygen wizard on the run page you can also see the used configuration and also the condensed form (this should be the same as the normal `doxygen -x Doxyfile`)

Comment: I've just pushed a proposed patch to github (pull request 8673, https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/8673).

Comment: Code has been integrated in master on github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doxygen 1.9 2021 does not understand PHP `array = [ ];`,

A workaround is by using old school: `array = ( );`

Note: see the difference between `[ ]`, and `array = ( );`

Comment: Probably your pointer (`(` <=> `[`) is better than mine. You mention version `doxygen 1.9 2021`, which version is this ? I only know at the moment, for the 1.9 series, the  doxygen versions `1.9.0` and `1.9.1` and further the current master `(1.9.2 (7fa3837cf2d93164df2cf2fc6697a27fea524d07)`, with the master the git ID, as reported by `doxygen -v`, should always be specified).

Comment: I've just pushed a proposed patch to github (pull request 8673, https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/8673).

Comment: Code has been integrated in master on github